# Merge a list of viewmodels into one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure if I am asking this correctly, but I'll do my best to explain and provide the code.

I have an ActionResult on a controller that loops through every year that is available, prints out results for each year id, and loops through until it's finished, then produces a final product.

The problem I am having is the sorting feature.  It sorts via every year instead of the whole thing as a table.  I figured the easiest way of fixing this so it is just one model instead of multiple separated by year is to somehow merge the list into one.

I am pretty new to C# MVC, so any helpful tips, tricks and examples would help immensely.  Also if you need any other code please ask and I will provide it.

**Controller**

```
// list of models, because you want ALL of them
            var managementModels = new List<CollectionsManagementViewModel>();
            var setupIds = _repository.GetAllYearSetupIds();

            foreach (var setupId in setupIds)
            {
                // new model created for each setup id
                var managementModel = _repository.GetOverdueBalances(type,page, pageLength,
                         setupId.YearSetupId, balancefilter,
                         sort, direction == Constants.ascending,
                         spreadsheetType);

                managementModel.Title = title + " Management";
                managementModels.Add(managementModel); // add model to list
            }

            // pass collection to view

            return View("CollectionsManagement", new OverpayViewModel { CollectionsManagementViewModels = managementModels});
```

**EDIT**
I have a table in my view that is sorted via what column is clicked on. It currently, when the column name is selected, sorts everything but keeps it in years, for example 4,5,6 in year 2015 is sorted 4,5,6. Then in year 2016 you have 1,2,3 and when you sort from that column it doesn't sort it 1,2,3,4,5,6 it sorts it, 4,5,6,1,2,3 because it's sorting it for every year and not as a whole table.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague as to what everything is (e.g. what _repository is backed by etc).

But assuming you're getting a bunch of these `CollectionsManagementViewModel`s, and you want to sort them by year before displaying them:

```
return View("CollectionsManagement", 
    new OverpayViewModel { 
        CollectionsManagementViewModels = 
            _repository
            .GetAllYearSetupIds()
            .Select(ysi => _repository.GetOverdueBalances(
                type,
                page,
                pageLength,
                ysi.YearSetupId,
                balanceFilter,
                spreadsheetType)    // Assuming the sort is optional
            .OrderBy(vm => vm.Year) // Assuming that the vm has a more sensible year property to sort numerically
    });
```

I **really** am having to make a lot of assumptions about your code, so please see [How to create a minimal, viable, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to better familiarise yourself with how you're best likely to get an answer here.

Comment: Thank you, I will edit my question as needed.  This code is so elegant.